# Confusing offsets in shapefile written by QGIS/OGR

Tags: qgis, ogr

I think I'm stuck here.

A shapefile has been updated in QGIS. Records have been deleted and those records have been marked with an asterix in the first byte of the record in the dbf file.
I open the shapefile in a C program to convert it to postGIS. The deleted records are skipped. Things happen to the next record after a deleted record, not after the first deleted record though. The shx file says that the offset for the next record after the deleted record is 30948 and the accumulated offset in the shp file says 28740. Neither is right, or rather when you start reading in the shp file at the two offsets you land up in the middle of a point stream and not at the start of a record header. The offset 28740 should be right because that is what you get when you add up the offset of the deleted record and the contentlength of the deleted record.

The conclusion is that the shape is corrupt. But what is driving me nuts is that you can load the shape file into QGIS and it is shown correctly.

What have I missed.How can QGIS handle this.

Comment: I think only DBF files allow marking a record as deleted, while the SHP/SHX specification do not. Meaning QGIS does something non-standard and leaves it in a wrong state. Check out http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf. Perhaps QGIS has a "Compact" function.

Comment: Since QGIS is simply using OGR to read/write files this is really an OGR question.